# Convert Java object with embedded objects to a JSON with list of attributes and list of values and vice versa

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

In my Spring project I have several objects that should be serialized to a specific JSON format.

```
public class Person {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String height;
   private Address address;
}
```

and

```
public class Address {
   private String street;
   private String city;
   private String phone;
}
```

Let assume that Person.height and Address.phone should not appear in the JSON.
The resulting JSON should look like

```
{
  "attributes": ["id", "name", "street", "city"],
  "values": [12345, "Mr. Smith", "Main street", "Chicago"]
}
```

I can create create a standard JSON with an ObjectMapper and some annotations like @JsonProperty and @JsonUnwrapped where I disable some SerializationFeatures. But at the moment I'm not able to create such a JSON.

Is there an easy way to create this JSON? And how would the way back (deserialization) look like?

Comment: Why don't you create a POJO that reflects your wanted JSON structure and populate it accordingly? This would be much more readable than some annotation magic.

Comment: Unfortunately, both classes Person and Address are required. Of course, I can use a converter to map the values ​​into a new pojo with a flat structure. But such a converter is then directly fixed on the classes used. A more general solution would be nicer, because this JSON with attributes and values ​​should also work for other classes.
I now have another specification: The attribute names in the JSON object are not always named as they come from the POJOs. For example, "name" could also be called "lastName". Or completely different.

Comment: I do think that there are advantages here if you use annotations. "@JsonProperty" or "@SerializedName" spring to mind. But in my implementation I currently use both (for the way to generate the JSON and the way back...).
At the moment I can only think of a 2-step solution here: Original POJO to a flat POJO. And then convert this to a JSON using the ObjectMapper.
A very generically POJO-JSON converter that does this in one step would be cool. I.e. independent of the POJO class used and independent of an internal POJO structure.
Of course in both ways then...

Comment: Perhaps there is a way with an own defined and implemented annotation that holds the name of the attribute of the JSON. And the same annotation can be used for the way back. Main problem in my eyes would be to map a JSON attribute to an embedded POJO attribute like e.g. "city" from the example above.

Answer (score 0):

There are good reasons Jackson doesn't serializes maps in this format. It's less readable and also harder to deserialize properly.

But if you just create another POJO it's very easy to achieve what you want to do:

```
public class AttributeList {

    public static AttributeList from(Object o) {
        return from(new ObjectMapper().convertValue(o, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}));
    }

    public static AttributeList from(Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        return new AttributeList(attributes);
    }

    private final List<String> attributes;
    private final List<Object> values;

    private AttributeList(Map<String, Object> o) {
        attributes = new ArrayList<>(o.keySet());
        values = new ArrayList<>(o.values());
    }

}
```

Comment: I know the disadvantages of this format, but unfortunately this is a requirement. Hence the search for an elegant solution. Your answer definitely helps and after adjusting the ObjectMapper and serialization of this POJO above I get exactly the JSON I'm looking for. Now I just have to worry about the way back... Thank you :-) !